# package is installed but command not available under M-x

Tags: init-file, package, list-packages

I installed darkroom via the package manager in my GNU Emacs 25.3.1 (x86_64-w64-mingw32). `M-x package-list` shows the package as installed and in fact are the files in the respective folder, the command, however, `M-x darkroom-mode` does not work, i.e. response with [no match].

The relevant parts of my  `.emacs looks` like this:

```
(package-initialize)

(custom-set-variables
'(package-selected-packages (quote (darkroom auctex))))
```

Is there something missing? Is it maybe still running? I'm grateful for any suggestions,

Comment: Please don't show your whole init file here, and ask that we find the problem. Instead, bisect it to find out where the problem lies. What package is supposed to define the command you want? Perhaps that package is not getting loaded. Are you sure that the function is a command (so you can use it with `M-x`)? These are things to check.

Comment: @Drew I wasn't aware of that, other helpdesks always ask for ALL the information, so I wanted to provide the right away. I narrowed it down to the parts that seem relevant to me.

Comment: @Nils Note, that [this site](https://stackexchange.com/about) is community driven even if it is commercially hosted. So this is not a [helpdesk](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Help_desk).

Comment: No problem. Thanks for narrowing it down. That makes a big difference and makes the Q & A more helpful for others who might have a similar question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The elpa-version `darkroom-0.1.el` of [darkroom](https://elpa.gnu.org/packages/darkroom-0.1.el) does not have an `;;;###autoload` before `(define-minor-mode darkroom-mode ...)` as [the github version](https://github.com/joaotavora/darkroom/blob/master/darkroom.el#L326) has.

That means that you can either install the [the github version](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/joaotavora/darkroom/master/darkroom.el) or put

`(autoload 'darkroom-mode "darkroom" nil t)`

into your [init file](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Init-File.html).

Comment: Thanks for your response, sadly, none of this solutions worked. Maybe I was something missing. However, I got it running with the elpa-version, see my answer.

Comment: @Nils I've corrected the `autoload` variant. You need to mark the function as interactive.

Comment: Your changes worked. Since this solution has a better performance than mine, I think this is the way to go. Thanks for your help.

Comment: @Nils Sorry about the hick-up I caused by forgetting the optional `interactive` argument of `autoload`.

Answer (score 0):

The solution for me was the following:

install the package via the package manager

```
M-x package-install RET darkroom RET
```

add the following lines to the init file:

```
(add-to-list 'load-path "PATH/TO/DARKROOM_EXTENSION_FOLDER")
;; something like c:/emacs/.emacs.d/elpa/darkroom-0.1/
(require 'darkroom)
```

the required package has to be the same name as the .el file. So if your extension has the name darkroom_foo.el you need to require:

```
(require 'darkroom_foo)
```

Comment: The package directory is added to `load-path` by `package-install`/ `package-initialize`. You don't need to do that. I tried to avoid the `require` with `autoload` in my answer. `require` increases the startup time by loading the packages. Contrary to that the packages are loaded on demand by `autoload`. My corrected answer should do the job.